# "(component) is not defined", can't find the bug?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a simple Tab component within React. However, for some reason, my component 'Tab' is showing as not defined when called within the  component.

I have imported it into the Tablist.js component so it is completely throwing me off. Does anybody have any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Code:

App.js

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import Tablist from "./components/Tablist";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: "Home",
    };
  }

  setSelected = (tab) => {
    this.setState({ selected: tab });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="App">
        <Tablist
          tabs={["Home", "Second", "Third"]}
          selected={this.state.selected}
          setSelected={this.setSelected}
        >
          <Tab isSelected={this.state.selected === "Home"}>
            <p>Tab 1</p>
          </Tab>
          <Tab isSelected={this.state.selected === "Second"}>
            <p>Tab 2</p>
          </Tab>
          <Tab isSelected={this.state.selected === "Third"}>
            <p>Tab 3</p>
          </Tab>
        </Tablist>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Tablist.js

```
import React from "react";
import Tab from "./Tabs";

class Tablist extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          {this.props.tabs.map((tab) => {
            const active = tab === this.props.selected ? "active" : "";

            return (
              <li key={tab}>
                <a
                  className={active}
                  onClick={() => this.props.setSelected(tab)}
                >
                  {tab}
                </a>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tablist;
```

Tabs.js

```
import React from "react";

class Tab extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    if (this.props.isSelected) {
      return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
    }
  }
}

export default Tab;
```

Comment: `Tab` is not available to `App.js`, only `TabList` is, you need to import `Tab` as well

Comment: but, Tab is imported into Tablist, then Tablist is imported through to App, should that not work?

Comment: Imports are available only for the component you are importing them in, they don't transfer to parent components.

Comment: ohhh, my bad, thank you!

Comment: No worries, happy to help